# ValueError: Length of values (0) does not match length of index (2)

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, lstm, valueerror

I've been trying to fix the error using pd.Series, pd.array, and pd.DataFrame but it tells me that the data must be 1-dimensional and I can't find the remedy for both.

Without pd.Series, pd.array, pd.DataFrame
[V1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p75s8.png)

With pd.Series, pd.array, pd.DataFrame
[V2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEJ7s.png)

A fix for one of the errors would do just fine for me

If it helps, this is the data it's suppose to process and it has 6087 rows x 2 columns
[V3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUZLc.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: This is missing the details of the relevant variable (the one that is indexed).